# How to approve a sharepoint task using a WP7 application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, sharepoint-2010

I have sharepoint site on microsoft sharepoint2010.

Now i have to create a WP7 application using which i can approve and reject the the tasks from mobile.

i have created a task with approval workflow.

I have used Lists.asmx(webservice of sharepoint) to display list of tasks assigned to person and is working fine with my mobile application, but unable to find how to approve and reject tasks.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to this question [Approve a SharePoint workflow task using SharePoint Web Services / Object Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814828/approve-a-sharepoint-workflow-task-using-sharepoint-web-services-object-model)

In order to use this code you need to reference Microsoft.SharePoint dll, however I am not sure if this is possible on a WP7 device.

Answer (score 1):

A running workflow adds task to a tasks list that specify the person assigned to each task. You can access this list using the listdata.svc(you can query the service) or lists.asmx service.

See [Approval Workflow scenario on MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee704556.aspx) and [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/windows-sharepoint-services-help/view-workflow-tasks-HA010164127.aspx) on how to locate custom tasks list

When a workflow template is installed on a site and associated with a document library, list, site, or content type, a site user can start an instance of a workflow.

The process starts when the workflow initiator selects a document and starts an instance of a workflow.

The initiator creates a workflow instance from this association.

The user customizes this new instance and starts it.

The running instance of the workflow adds a task to the task list of a participant.

The approval workflow that is used in this scenario assigns these tasks sequentially. However, you can assign tasks to many participants at the same time, which allows tasks to be performed in parallel.

Participants in the workflow can learn about tasks that the workflow has assigned to them by checking their task lists.

Each participant interacts with the running instance of the workflow to complete assigned tasks.

Comment: How are you going to attach credentials to the service call when you are on a WP7 device?

Comment: @Rob, I do not think OP had any issues with attaching credentials. OP made successful calls to lists.asmx web service